# GPSD simple query's

Tags: linux, gps, archlinux, gpsd

I need some information from my GPSD server running on my NTP master server.

- Amount of satellites it is seeing
- Which satellites it is using for the positon fix (maybe also SNR)
- Which satellites it is seeing since there are a lott of them (is this possible?)

I am going to output this to PHP, so it must be simple

Answer (score 1):

The GPSD source contains the file gpsd.php which can deliver the current position and satellite info ("skyview") either as a finished HTML page or as a JSON string. So you need to make sure a web server with PHP support runs on your master server and you can call `http://ntp-server/path/to/gpsd.php` to get it. Append `?op=json` to the URL to return the JSON result.

You can get just the php file here: https://github.com/yazug/gpsd/raw/master/gpsd.php

Answer (score 1):

[Beat Bolli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646573/246330): I think you meant this one: https://github.com/yazug/gpsd/raw/master/gpsd.php.in (they have renamed it)

It suggests to use `?poll;` function, but it hangs to me when I try to read the response...